# Call a function in function.php Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm studying PHP and have a basic question,

I have this code in the page `portfolio.php`

```
<?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        $portfolio_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) : 

            echo '<div id="primary" class="hfeed">';

            while( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) : $portfolio_query->the_post();

            // project url
            $portfolio_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_portfolio_project_url', true);
            if( !empty($portfolio_url) ) 
                $portfolio_button_copy = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_portfolio_project_url_copy', true);

        ?>
```

I would like to `echo` `$portfolio_url` in my `function.php`
Any reference for more study in this case would be appreciated.

Comment: Umm, why do you want to echo into your functions.php file?

Comment: Because i have a function in my function.php which echo '<a>' tag and i wanna to echo the 'href' there!

Comment: Ok, so where are you calling your function?

Comment: At the portfolio.php and single-portfolio.php please note that i'm customizing a Themezilla's theme.

Comment: You don't want to `echo` $portfolio_url; you want to pass it as an argument/parameter to the function instead. You'll need to alter the function in question so that it accepts arguments, and then when calling your function you can add `$portfolio_url` as the argument.

Comment: @Dre I added the following code into my function.php /*---------------
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        $portfolio_query = new WP_Query($args);
while( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) : $portfolio_query->the_post();

            // project url
            $portfolio_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_portfolio_project_url', true);
            endwhile;
but still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but if you need to pass a url to a function then you can do so with an argument:

```
    function your_function($url) {
        // Do whatever you want with $url here, like:
        echo '<a href="'.$url.'">A link</a>';
    }
```

You can save the above into `functions.php`. 
Based on your comments, I *think* what you're trying to do is take your code in `portfolio.php` and turn it into a function that you can call elsewhere. In that case you need to actually define it as a function:

```
    function get_portfolio_url() {
        // Insert your existing code in here...
        // Then you can either echo $portfolio_url:
        echo $portfolio_url;
        // Or you can just return it if you plan on doing other things with it
        return $portfolio_url
    }
```

You can insert the above function into `functions.php`. Then you can call it anywhere with `get_portfolio_url()`. Technically you would no longer require `portfolio.php`, since you've created a function that does exactly the same thing. Be aware that you don't need to create separate PHP files for every function you require; you can just define them as separate functions in one location and then call them as necessary (which is essentially what `functions.php` is for in WordPress; a single file to hold all the functions your theme uses).

Comment: I think it should be clear now: think you have a function in the example.php and you want to call that function in example2.php. . I have a function ($portfolio.php) which i wanted to call that function in another php page! Does is it make sense right now? thank you!

Comment: I *think* you just want to call one function in another file; see edited answer above.